# Multiple setTimeout to hide controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

In my page I have:

> ```
> Dim sb As New StringBuilder
> sb.AppendLine("function pageLoad(sender, args) {")
> sb.AppendLine("  setTimeout( function() { $(""#ContentPlaceHolder1_tbcTables_ctl00_lblCostCenterImportMessage"").fadeOut(3000); }, 6000 ); ")
> sb.AppendLine("  setTimeout( function() { $(""#ContentPlaceHolder1_tbcTables_ctl00_lblCustomerImportMessage"").fadeOut(3000); }, 6000 ); ")
> sb.AppendLine("};")
> ```

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "scriptlblTimeOut", sb.ToString, True)
```

This is working for the first label to fade out, but the second doesn't do that.
How can I put multiple fade outs in the pageload?

rg.
Eric

Comment: Any chance the id of the second label isn't `lblCustomerImportMessage`? - Maybe a typo?

Answer (score 0):

strange, I checked the name of the second label, it was not wrong, then I ran the page again and now it is working....

Don't you just hate it when that happens. :-)